# formular consulta para mostrar datos

Tags: php, mysql

como hago para que en mi tabla me arroje las facturas que fueron a credito y de contado ya que si pongo un and en la consulta no me arroja datos por que por decir en una fecha solo hay de credito y en la consulta pido ambos datos credito y contado y no cumplo con la condición y si pongo un or me arroja datos pero fuera de la fecha.

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    //preguntamos la zona horaria
    $zonahoraria = date_default_timezone_get();
$hora=date ('G:i');
?>

<div align="center">
<font size="+2" color="#FFFFFF"><strong>FACTURAS Y REMISIONES DEL DIA: <?php echo $fecha?>, A LAS: <?php echo $hora?></strong></font>

<table class="tablafac">
<tr>
<th>FACTURA</th>
<th>TIPO DE PAGO</th>
<th>FECHA</th>
<?php
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT factura,tipopago,fechafactura from facturacion WHERE fechafactura='$fecha' AND entregada='on' AND tipopago='CONTADO' OR tipopago='CREDITO'");
$contador =mysql_num_rows($query);
if($contador> 0)
{ 
while ($array=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {  echo "<tr>
    <td>".$array[0]."</td>
    <td>".$array[1]."</td>
    <td>".$array[2]."</td>
    </tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "<tr>
    <td>No hay registros</td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de lograr lo que quieres es usando parentesis asi:

```
SELECT factura,tipopago,fechafactura 
from facturacion 
WHERE fechafactura='$fecha' AND entregada='on' AND (tipopago='CONTADO' OR tipopago='CREDITO')
```

Comment: muchas gracias , funciono era algo tan sencillo pero andaba perdido , gracias

Answer (score 1):

Prueba haciendo la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT factura,tipopago,fechafactura from facturacion WHERE fechafactura='$fecha' AND entregada='on' AND (tipopago='CONTADO' OR tipopago='CREDITO')");
```